# Retrieving data from SQLite database into listView

Tags: android, sqlite

Instead of retriving the data it return package name in each list I didn't find my mistake.Plz help me .This is my DbHelper class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper

```
 public List<DICTIONARY> getAllcontacts() {
            List<DICTIONARY> meaningList = new ArrayList<DICTIONARY>();

            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Table_Name;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DICTIONARY dictionary = new DICTIONARY();
                    dictionary.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    dictionary.setWord(cursor.getString(1));
                    dictionary.setMeaning(cursor.getString(2));
                    // Adding contact to list
                    meaningList.add(dictionary);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // return meaning list
            return meaningList;
        }
```

This is my MainActivity class

```
 DbHelper db = new DbHelper(MainActivity.this);
  List<DICTIONARY> dictionary = db.getAllContacts(); 
        ArrayAdapter<DICTIONARY> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DICTIONARY>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dictionary);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change it**

```
// Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(dictionary);
```

**To**

```
                meaningList.add(dictionary);
```

It should be like

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DICTIONARY dictionary = new DICTIONARY();
                    dictionary.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    dictionary.setWord(cursor.getString(1));
                    dictionary.setMeaning(cursor.getString(2));
                    // Adding contact to Meaning List
                    meaningList.add(dictionary);//Changed Here
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

Comment: now it's working i find out my mistakes thanks Amit Gupta for helping

Comment: How to display this in Listview

Comment: i am upvoting your answer but please tell me how to display this in list view i have edited my question check it once

Comment: @Illusionist you should use CustomAdapter to populate in the ListView. Please go through my blog http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-checkbox-and.html , take a look how.